# Are there UI-builders or automated UIs based on an ABI + contract address?

Tags: abi, gui

In order to demonstrate a contract, I want to use a generated UI, based on the ABI.

The contract runs on local network, or on one of the testnets.

Two options that I am aware of, and that work, but have downsides:

- Remix can make a UI for the contract, in its right sidebar, and allows loading a contract from an address. It (appears to) build that UI from the ABI, extracted from the contract you have in your code-editor. It is an IDE, and so it is focused on development.
- Mist can load a contract based on the ABI + contract address, but requires an application to be installed, configured and so forth.

Basically, I'm looking for something very alike the Mist-Contract feature, but then in a (simple) HTML/web3.js implementation; like Remix, but far simpler.

Requiring MetaMask is not a problem. And the UI should be workable, but does not need fancy UI designs or even customisation.

Being able to log the transactions and the emitted events is a pro.

Is there such a project, or site?

Comment: I got downvotes and closed when I asked this, so I won't be doing that. Just let me know when you find something, brother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out https://wallet.ethereum.org .

You have to load the `ABI` and provide a contract address but its essentially what your'e looking for.